# How to make a database for a Quiz

Tags: android

I have made a Quiz App which has multiple answers in the form of radiobuttons. I want to store the  answer of each question  in the  SQLite Database  and I have to also count  the options.Like if the user choose option A for the first question then the count of A should be 1 and if likewise the user choose A again for the second question then count of A should be 2 and if the user choose B for the first question then count of B should be 1 and after that if the user choose option B for the second question so count of B should be 2 likewise for option C also

But there is another problem also if the user goes back and and changes option on any question so the option which he has choose previously its count should be decreased by 1 and again which option he choose that options counter should be increased by 1

how to make this type of Database.I have used viewpager in this code and these are the fragments which I have made seperately for each question.

```
package com.example.android.viewpager1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    Databasehelper mydb;

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
        initialisePaging();
        mydb=new Databasehelper(this);

    }

    private void initialisePaging()
    {
        List<Fragment> fragments =new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment3.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment4.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment5.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment6.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment7.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment8.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment9.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment10.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment11.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment12.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment13.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment14.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment15.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment16.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment17.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment18.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment19.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment20.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment21.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment22.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment23.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment24.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment25.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment26.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment27.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment28.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment29.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment30.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment31.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment32.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment33.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment34.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment35.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment36.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment37.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment38.class.getName()));
       mPagerAdapter = new com.example.android.viewpager1.PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
       ViewPager pager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
       pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    }
```

This is my fragment code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question 10"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nails"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rough, dry less growth"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Glossy copper coloured"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Long white strong"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />

     </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you really need 38 fragments to ask your question? Could you make a [mcve], please?

Comment: How many option do you have for a single question? Is it dynamic or static?

Comment: I have 38 fragments in which there is each question with 3 options and then I have put these all 38 fragments in a list and then on that list I have applied viewpager adapter now I think you must have understood

Comment: Till now It is static but after wards I will connect it with server

Comment: It has 3  options per questions